# Find the $x$ value for when the expression is takes the minimum value

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, radicals, maxima-minima

> Let $E(x)=\sqrt{x^2-2x+5}+\sqrt{x^2-8x+25}.$ Find the $x$ value for when this expression take it's minimum value.

Using the derivative it's pretty hard... and I think not indicated for this problem... I thought about using the inequality of means. First, rewrite:

$E(x)=\sqrt{x^2-2x+5}+\sqrt{x^2-8x+25}$ as $E(x)=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4}+\sqrt{(x-4)^2+9}$..

But I don't know how to continue...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sqrt{\left(x-1\right)^2+4}=\sqrt{\left(x-1\right)^2+\left(0-\left(-2\right)\right)^2}
$$
is exactly the distance between point $A:\left(x,0\right)$ and point $B:\left(1,-2\right)$, and that
$$
\sqrt{\left(x-4\right)^2+9}=\sqrt{\left(x-4\right)^2+\left(0-3\right)^2}
$$
is exactly the distance between point $A:\left(x,0\right)$ and point $C:\left(4,3\right)$. Therefore, you are to find some point $A$ on the $x$-axis such that
$$
d(A,B)+d(A,C)
$$
is minimized (i.e., the total distance of the red segments in the figure below is minimized), where $d(A,B)$ denotes the distance between points $A$ and $B$.
[image]

Gratefully, it is obvious that, as $A$ falls on the dashed blue segment, the total distance witnesses its minimum, since this dashed blue segment yields the minimum distance between points $B$ and $C$. Due to the triangular inequality, any other position of $A$ would make
$$
d(A,B)+d(A,C)>d(B,C).
$$
Therefore, the very $A$ that minimizes the total distance should be the point on the dashed blue segment. Then combined with the fact that $A$ is a point on the $x$-axis, this $A$ would have no choice but to be $\left(11/5,0\right)$.

Comment: So, $\frac {11
}5$?

Comment: @C.Cristi: Perfect! $x=11/5$ seems to be the answer.

Comment: Also can you be more explicit with why you did what you did? And what made you think of that? and do you think it would work using the derivative? Also Why the intersection of the line that crosses $(1,-2), (4,3)$ gives me my minimum of that expression?

Comment: @C.Cristi: Er... I thought you were seeking for some shortcut. Hopefully this type of questions are _designed_ to have a default shortcut, i.e., considering the geometric interpretation of $E(x)$. So as you realize that you need to minimize the total distance between the three points, you are approaching the answer.

Comment: @C.Cristi: (con't) Generally, the least distance between two points is a straight line. Unfortunately, we have three points there. Yet you could see that the distance between $\left(1,2\right)$ and $\left(x,0\right)$ and that between $\left(1,-2\right)$ and $\left(x,0\right)$ are identical. Therefore, the problem reduces to find the least distance between two points.

Comment: @C.Cristi: Also, taking the derivative is always working. But just as you mentioned, this is really tedious and involved, and we tend to turn to this method only if we have no easy alternative.

Comment: true, i was seeking for some shortcut, but why $(x,0)$, though?

Comment: @C.Cristi: You can choose other points as well. The key secret lies in that this point must appear in both the first and the second square root term. For example, if you choose $(x,1)$, it is also fine. Then the first term tells the distance between $(x,1)$ and $(1,3)$ (or $(1,-1)$), while the second between $(x,1)$ and $(4,4)$ (or $(4,-2)$).

Comment: can you make a drawing, so I could understand better, please?

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: @C.Cristi: Sorry for my delayed response; I got seriously wounded while jogging :-( I just updated my answer, with a picture therein. Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: Thank you for your feedback :-)

Comment: @hypernova thanks indeed, and hope you will get better soon with your injury!

Comment: @C.Cristi: Thank you for your kind wishes!

Comment: @hypernova Why there must be $(0-(-2))^2$ and not $(0-2)^2$ or even $(2-0)^2$?

Comment: @C.Cristi: 'cause this point works best. If you put $(0-2)^2$ or other choices, the geometric interpretation would not be that intuitive.

Comment: @hypernova So if I were to have other numbers in that expression I would have to discover "the best" interpretation myself? Also... does this method *always* work?

Comment: @C.Cristi: Exactly. But there are only a few interpretations in total, and you will not miss it. This method applies as long as the cost function is of the form $\sqrt{a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1}+\sqrt{a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Using Minkowski's inequality:
$$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4}+\sqrt{(x-4)^2+9}=\\
\sqrt{(x-1)^2+2^2}+\sqrt{(4-x)^2+3^2}\ge \\
\sqrt{(x-1+4-x)^2+(2+3)^2}=\sqrt{3^2+5^2}=\sqrt{34}.$$
The equality occurs when $(x-1,2)||(4-x,3)$, that is:
$$\frac{3}{2}(x-1)=4-x \Rightarrow x=\frac{11}{5}.$$